# what does this mean in c# while converting to a unsigned int 32

Tags: c#

```
(uint)Convert.ToInt32(elements[0]) << 24;
```

Comment: Good rule when saying "this" in anything is to make it explicit what you're referring to. Are you referring to the whole line of code? the cast? the bit-shift operator? the number 24?

Comment: And it would help if you accepted answers on some of your previous questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The << is the [left shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w(VS.80).aspx).

Given that the number is a binary number, it will shift all the bits the specified amount to the left.

If we have

```
2 << 1
```

This will take the number 2 in binary (00000010) and shift it to the left one bit. This gives you 4 (000000100).

**Overflows**

Note that once you get to the very left, the bits are discarded. So assuming you are working with an 8 bit sized integer *(I know c# uint like you have in your example is 32 bits - I dont want to have to type out a 32 bit digit, so just assume we are on 8 bits)*

```
255 << 1
```

will return 254 (11111110).

**Use**

Being very careful of the overflows mentioned before, bit shifting is a very fast way to multiply or divide by 2. In a highly optimised environment (such as games) this is a very useful way to perform arithmetic very fast.

However, in your example, it is taking only the right most 8 bits of the number making them the left most 8 bits (multiplying it by 16,777,216) . Why you would want do this, I could only guess.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to [Shift operators.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Mongus Pong said, shifts are usually used to multiply and divide very fast. (And can cause weird problems due to overflow).

I'm going to go out on a limb and trying to guess what your code is doing.

**If** elements[0] is a byte element(that is to say, it contains only 8 bits), then this code will result in straight-forward multiplication by 2^24. Otherwise, it will drop the 24 high-order bits and multiply by 2^24.

Comment: My code gets the client ip address and checks it with the range of specified IP's in the database table. As direct comparision of ip address is not possible, I splitted it, so that it has 4 elements in the array. After shifting the bits, I add the sum and compare it with the ip range in the DB(The ip ranges in the DB is also splitted using the same logic).